# OleDbDataAdapter for MS Access updating table, why doesn't my update work?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what it is that i'm doing incorrectly here- in the debugger the changes made to the filename are made correctly to the dataset that i'm pulling from for my update command, but when i check the database afterwards no changes have been made... so i'm a bit confused...

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                               "Data Source=J:\\Physics.mdb"))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select thesisID, filename FROM Theses", con))
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                con.Open();
                dbAdapter.Fill(ds);

                for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["filename"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["filename"].ToString().Replace(',', '_');
                    string newFileName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["filename"].ToString();
                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["thesisID"].ToString());
                    using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                       updateCommand.CommandText = "update theses set filename = @newFileName where thesisID = @ID";
                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newFileName", newFileName);

                        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }



                }
                con.Close();
                }

        }
```

Comment: Reverse the order of your parameter adding! It's the nature of OleDBCommand I'm afraid - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476770/oledbcommand-parameters-order-and-priority. Other data providers, like SqlClient, support named parameters, and your code would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MichaelTodd. I wasn't aware that closed questions would still be "accessible"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reversing the order in which you are adding the parameters:

```
using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = con.CreateCommand()) 
{ 
   updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   updateCommand.CommandText = "update theses set filename = @newFileName where thesisID = @ID"; 
   updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newFileName", newFileName);
   updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);   
   updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

The reason for this is that [OleDb doesn't support named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476770/oledbcommand-parameters-order-and-priority), so the order in which you add them is important.

Note that it is often common to see OleDb queries expressed this way:

```
using (OleDbCommand updateCommand = con.CreateCommand()) 
{ 
   updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   updateCommand.CommandText = "update theses set filename = ? where thesisID = ?"; 
   updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "", ""...));
   updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", "", ""...));
   updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

This emphasises that the order is important - the question marks are merely placeholders which get replaced in the order in which parameters are added to the command.