# my update c# code is not working,can i update two relational table at once?

Tags: c#, windows

i was trying to update two tables at once, but i got some syntax error on update code could u give me some idea? the insert code works perfect and i tried to copy the insert code and edit on update button clicked

here is my code

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data source= C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\crt_db.accdb";

        try
        {


            conn.Open();
            String Name = txtName.Text.ToString();

            String AR = txtAr.Text.ToString();
            String Wereda = txtWereda.Text.ToString();
            String Kebele = txtKebele.Text.ToString();
            String House_No = txtHouse.Text.ToString();
            String P_O_BOX = txtPobox.Text.ToString();
            String Tel = txtTel.Text.ToString();
            String Fax = txtFax.Text.ToString();
            String Email = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
            String Item = txtItem.Text.ToString();
            String Dep = txtDep.Text.ToString();
            String k = "not renwed";


            String Remark = txtRemark.Text.ToString();

            String Type = txtType.Text.ToString();
            String Brand = txtBrand.Text.ToString();
            String License_No = txtlicense.Text.ToString();
            String Date_issued = txtDate.Text.ToString();
            String my_querry = "update crtPro set  Name='" + Name + "',AR='" + AR + "',Wereda='" + Wereda + "',Kebele='" + Kebele + "',House_No='" + House_No + "',P_O_BOX='" + P_O_BOX + "',Tel='" + Tel + "',Fax='" + Fax + "',Email='" + Email + "',Item='" + Item + "',Dep='" + Dep + "','" + k + "',Remark='" + Remark + "' where Name='" + Name + "' ";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            String my_querry1 = "SELECT max(PID) FROM crtPro";
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry1, conn);

            string var = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();





            String ki = txtStatus.Text.ToString();
            String my_querry2 = "update crtItemLicense set PID=" + var + ",Type='" + Type + "',Brand='" + Brand + "',License_No='" + License_No + "',Date_issued='" + Date_issued + "' where PID=" + var + "";
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Message added succesfully");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed due to" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Not specifically related to your question but read about [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html).

Comment: Try to execute the query direct in database.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem based on the little information given (what database are you using for example - SQL Server 2012?), is that the *datatype* you are providing in the concatenated dynamic sql does not match the datatype of the column in the database. You've surrounded each value with quotes - which means it will be interpreted as a varchar. If you've got a date value in the wrong format (ie if Date_Issued is a date column) or if it is a number column, then it will error.

The solution is to replace your dynamic SQL with a parameterized query eg:

```
String my_querry = "update crtPro set Name=@name, AR=@ar, Wereda=@Wereda, etc ...";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myParam", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text.Trim()));
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can read about it further [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

PS Make sure your parameters are in the same order as they are used in the SQL, because oledbcommand doesn't actually care what you call them. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476770/oledbcommand-parameters-order-and-priority)