# Syntax error in query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```vb
With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableContacts (NameUser, Address, City, Phone, Fax, Note, Email) VALUES (@NameUser, @Address, @City, @Phone, @Fax, @Note, @Email)"
    With .Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@NameUser", txtName.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Fax", txtFax)
        .AddWithValue("@Note", txtNote.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@Email", txtTo.Text)

    End With

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    .Dispose()
End With
```

Can't find where is the problem.

All the debugger says is:

> {"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}

Comment: Its not about the @Email and this is access database

Comment: To those who vote to close as a "typo question" and upvote corresponding comments: If it was about a missing/invalid parameter, the error would be different.

Comment: `Note` is a reserved word. You need to enclose it in square brackets `[Note]`. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266

Comment: @GSerg I voted to close it as a typo. We don't need a Q&A for each and every reserved word. If you know of a good canonical, please VTC as dupe.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Ok it makes sense if you VTC knowing it's about the keyword. The close vote appeared earlier than your comment so it looked like people are VTCing on the basis of the missing `@`.

Comment: GSerg your answer is helpful, Post it as answer so i can close this

Comment: @AnelH. That would be a wrong thing to do. Please click [the "That solved my problem!" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/147640).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

OleDbCommands don't support named parameters. You need to use question marks in your SQL statement and then just add the parameters in the correct order.

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableContacts (NameUser, Address, City, Phone, Fax, Note, Email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
With .Parameters
    .AddWithValue("?", txtName.Text)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtAddress.Text)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtCity.Text)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtPhone.Text)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtFax)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtNote.Text)
    .AddWithValue("?", txtTo.Text)
End With
```

Comment: While you are right that OleDb does not support named parameters, the OP's code would [work anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1476770/11683). This is not the source of the problem.

Comment: You do get a syntax error when your statement uses @ as a parameter prefix in the SQL statement. Using reserved words will also do that.

Comment: That is only true if you actually manually send the `@` in the query text. When you have a command object that was constructed with `@`, the `@` will not necessarily reach the database.