# Unrealistically Annoying 'Invalid Data Type in Criteria Expression'

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have the following query

```
public const string UpdateSample =
@"UPDATE subReceivingQC
SET Clerk=@Clerk, Comments=@Comments, CommentsProd=@CommentsProd, MassOff=@MassOff, 
    PalletID=@PalletID, QCDate=@QCDate, QtyInspected=@QtyInspected, StatusClerk=@StatusClerk,
    StatusSupervisor=@StatusSupervisor, Supervisor=@Supervisor, PackOut=@PackOut
WHERE GRV=@GRV AND PalletSeq=@PalletSeq AND SampleNo=@SampleNo";
```

And inserting the item with this code

```
// Update sample
query = DatabaseConstants.UpdateSample;
args = new DynamicParameters();

args.Add("@Clerk", sample.Clerk, DbType.String);
args.Add("@Comments", sample.Comments, DbType.String);
args.Add("@CommentsProd", sample.CommentsProd, DbType.String);
args.Add("@MassOff", sample.MassOff, DbType.String);
args.Add("@PackOut", sample.PackOut, DbType.String);
args.Add("@PalletID", sample.PalletID, DbType.String);
args.Add("@QCDate", sample.QCDate, DbType.Date);
args.Add("@QtyInspected ", sample.QtyInspected, DbType.Decimal);
args.Add("@StatusClerk", sample.StatusClerk, DbType.String);
args.Add("@StatusSupervisor", sample.StatusSupervisor, DbType.String);
args.Add("@Supervisor", sample.Supervisor, DbType.String);
args.Add("@GRV", sample.GRV, DbType.Int64);
args.Add("@PalletSeq", sample.PalletSeq, DbType.Int16);
args.Add("@SampleNo", sample.SampleNo, DbType.Int16);

using (var db = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    output += db.Execute(query, args);
}
```

Now `MassOff` and `PackOut` are both of type **double**, where the Access data type looks like this for both:

[image]

The weird thing here is that the code works perfectly for the property `MassOff`, but after adding the line for `PackOut` I get

> Invalid Data Type in Criteria Expression

I tried changing the parameter `DbType.Decimal` and `DbType.Double` but it makes no difference.

None of the parameters in my query are in the same order as they appear in the db, so I don't think that is the cause as then I would be seeing the same issue without the `PackOut` value.

For instance, when I try passing in these values:

**MassOff** : 9.5
**PackOut** : 70.5

It works for `MassOff` but not `PackOut`

How in God's name is this possible?

---

**Sample class**

```
public class Sample :
    QCObject, IGriddable
{
    private string imagesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesPath"];

    private string[] columnHeaders;
    public string[] ColumnHeaders {
        get
        {
            if(columnHeaders.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                return new string[] { "SampleNo", "Date", /*"QCDate",*/ "StatusClerk", "StatusSupervisor" };
            }
            else
            {
                return columnHeaders;
            }
        }
        set { columnHeaders = value;  } }


    private string rowLinkPrefix;
    public string RowLinkPrefix {
    get
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowLinkPrefix))
        {
            return $"/receiving/{GRV}/{Pallet.PalletSeq}/";
        }
        else
        {
            return rowLinkPrefix;
        }
    }
    set { rowLinkPrefix = value;  } }

    public bool Selectable { get; } = true;

    public Pallet Pallet { get; set; }

    // Should be 100 - (massoff/qtinspected) but building this manually 
    // at the moment due to lack of data integrity
    [DisplayName("Pack Out")]
    public double PackOut { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Pack Out Percentage")]
    public double PackoutPerc { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Percentage")]
    public double Perc { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Mass Off")]
    public double MassOff { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Production Comments")]
    public string CommentsProd { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Technical Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Quantity Inspected")]
    public double QtyInspected { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sample Number")]
    public int SampleNo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status Clerk")]
    public string StatusClerk { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status Supervisor")]
    public string StatusSupervisor { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Spec")]
    public string ProductSpec { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("PO Container")]
    public string POContainer { get; set; }

    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string Clerk { get; set; }

    // For required db params
    public string GRV { get; set; }
    public string PalletID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Pallet")]
    public string PalletSeq { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime QCDate { get; set; }
    public string Date { get { return QCDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); } } // My generic WebGrid solution does not alllow me to change thed ate formats, so use this instead

    // Each defect status needs to be saved as a (DB)subQCItems item
    public List<QCItem> Defects { get; set; } = new List<QCItem>();
    public IEnumerable<string> Users { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public Sample()
    {
        var access = new Access();
        Users = access.GetUsers();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Images
    {
        get
        {
            string physicalDir;
            var dir = Path.Combine(imagesPath, $@"{Pallet.Grv.GRVNo}\{Pallet.PalletSeq}\{SampleNo}\");
            physicalDir = dir;

            if (Path.IsPathRooted(dir))
            {
                physicalDir = dir;
            }
            else
            {
                physicalDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dir);
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(physicalDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalDir);

            foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(physicalDir).Where(f => f != null))
            {
                yield return Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            }
        }
    }



    public void SaveImages(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files.Where(f => f != null))
        {
            var dir = $@"{imagesPath}/{Pallet.Grv.GRVNo}/{Pallet.PalletSeq}/{SampleNo}";
            var physicalDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dir);

            var imageDirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalDir);
            var counter = imageDirInfo.EnumerateFiles().Count() + 1;

            var path = Path.Combine($@"{physicalDir}", $"{counter}{Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)}");
            file.SaveAs(path);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any inner exceptions?

Comment: could you please show the class `sample`?

Comment: @vasily.sib There are no inner exceptions

Comment: `args.Add` the parameters in the same order they appear in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Bassie, can u please show the values that u supplied for `MassOff` that perfectly work and `PackOut` that gives u error?

Comment: @Bassie: by **HansUp** comment above, try to put `args.Add("@PackOut", sample.PackOut, DbType.String);` line after this line => `args.Add("@Supervisor", sample.Supervisor, DbType.String);`

Comment: @HansUp That worked. Write an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @HansUp, this is actually your solution, so add this as answer, OP will accept it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OleDbCommand parameters order and priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476770/oledbcommand-parameters-order-and-priority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLEDB ignores parameter names.  `args.Add` the parameters in the same order they appear in the `UPDATE` statement

```
args.Add("@Clerk", sample.Clerk, DbType.String);
args.Add("@Comments", sample.Comments, DbType.String);
args.Add("@CommentsProd", sample.CommentsProd, DbType.String);
args.Add("@MassOff", sample.MassOff, DbType.String);
args.Add("@PalletID", sample.PalletID, DbType.String);
args.Add("@QCDate", sample.QCDate, DbType.Date);
args.Add("@QtyInspected ", sample.QtyInspected, DbType.Decimal);
args.Add("@StatusClerk", sample.StatusClerk, DbType.String);
args.Add("@StatusSupervisor", sample.StatusSupervisor, DbType.String);
args.Add("@Supervisor", sample.Supervisor, DbType.String);
args.Add("@PackOut", sample.PackOut, DbType.String);
args.Add("@GRV", sample.GRV, DbType.Int64);
args.Add("@PalletSeq", sample.PalletSeq, DbType.Int16);
args.Add("@SampleNo", sample.SampleNo, DbType.Int16);
```